# (Python) Como impedir que métodos sejam acessados a partir do valor de algum atributo

Tags: python

Talvez não tenha ficado muito claro o titulo, mas eu queria que só fosse possível usar um método em um objeto, caso um ou mais de seus atributos estejam de uma certa forma. Por exemplo: Uma classe Tv que tem diversos métodos, para aumentar, diminuir, mudar canal, ligar, desligar. Como mostra o codigo abaixo (neste caso removi todos os metodos e atributos que não auxiliam no entendimento da duvida):

## Removi tudo do codigo que não ajudava em nada no entendimento da duvida

```
'''python
class Tv:
  def __self__(self, ligado=False, volume=0):#apenas define os atributos
    self.ligado = ligado
    self.volume = volume

  def altera_volume(self, novo_volume):#ele so faz mudar o valor do atributo "volume"
    self.volume = novo_volume

  def botao_on(self):#ou seja, esta meio que precionando aquele botaozinho de ligar a tv
    if self.ligado == False:#ou seja se a tv estiver desligada, ele vai ligar ela. ou seja "ligado" sera verdadeiro
      self.ligado == True
    else:#ou seja, se a tv estiver ligada o atributo ligado será falso
      self.ligado == False

#Nada do que esta escrito dentro dos metodos "altera_volume" e "botao_on" importa, a unica coisa que importa é que "altera_volume" só
#pode ser usado se o atributo "ligado" for verdadeiro, ou seja olha o que aconteceria abaixo

televisao = Tv()#ou seja televisao é uma Tv desligada com volume 0
televisao.alterar_volume(100)#Aqui esta o problema, como é possivel alterar o volume com a tv desligada?

#Tem alguma forma de proibir o uso do metodo "alterar_volume" até que o atributo "ligado" tenha o valor que eu quero?
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi direito, mas acho que você quer impedir o acesso direto aos atributos da classe. Se for esse o caso terá de nomear os atributos com dunderscore ou underline duas vezes antes do nome da variável, exemplo:`self.volume = volume para self.__volume = volume`. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Na verdade eu queria que so fosse possivel usar o metodo "altera_volume" se o atributo "ligado" tivesse um valor verdadeiro. Eu até poderia colocar um IF para verificar isso, mas se tivessem muitos metodos (tipo uns 50 ou 100) ficaria complicado colocar um IF para cada um deles. Dai queria saber se existe alguma forma mais pratica de fazer isso

Comment: voce pode colocar o if no metodo altera volume e chama-lo a partir dos outros. Em altera volume você verifica se esta ligado daí se estiver aplica a mudança de volume.

Comment: Em def botao_on você retorna o estado self.ligado: `def botao_on(self):#ou seja, esta meio que precionando aquele botaozinho de ligar a tv
    if self.ligado == False:#ou seja se a tv estiver desligada, ele vai ligar ela. ou seja "ligado" sera verdadeiro
      self.ligado == True
    else:#ou seja, se a tv estiver ligada o atributo ligado será falso
      self.ligado == False                                                                                                         return self.ligado`

Comment: Neste caso precisaria colocar um IF em todos os metodos para verificar isso? porque se tivesse diversos metodos, como "muda_canal", "poem_mudo", "reinicia"... eu precisaria verificar em cada metodo. ou até mesmo se tivesse muitos mais metodos.

Comment: Se você tiver de verificar sim, mas a diferença é que vc vai retornar o valor do estado de forma que todos vejam com return self.ligado, mas poderia também aninhar com o if caso ligado e assim executaria as outras funções. No caso da tv ligada o volume e outras funções seria ativadas automaticamente ou teria um comando ?

Comment: Supondo que esse programa foi rodado, dai entraria no modo interativo. eu poderia instanciar um outro objeto, mas se o atributo ligado estiver com valor False ainda sim consiguiria utilizar os métodos dele. Como você eu poderia fazer uma verificação. O problema e que poderiam ser muitos metodos e ter que criar uma verificação para cada um dos métodos seria complicado. Mas os métodos não seriam ativados automaticamente, apenas se escrevesse. Na verdade eu nem sei como faz para ativar automaticamente

Answer (score 1):

Esse é um bom caso onde utilizamos as exceções. Exceções são quando algo imprevisto acontece, elas são provenientes de erros de lógica ou acesso a recursos não disponíveis.

Sempre que uma exceção ocorre, a pilha de execução do programa é interrompida até que algum tratamento seja feito, senão o próprio programa é interrompido lançando a exceção no console.

Você pode ler mais sobre exceções em python [aqui](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-python-orientacao-objetos/excecoes-e-erros/).

Analisando sua classe TV, poderiamos criar uma exceção caso alguma ação seja feita e a tv esteja desligada. Essa exceção seria parecida com o código a seguir:

```
class TvDesligadaException(Exception):
  def __init__(self, message):
     self.message = message

  def __str__(self):
   return repr(self.message)
```

Logo, na classe tv, caso o metódo para aumentar volume seja chamado com a tv desligada, você pode lançar a exceção avisando que tal operação não é possível.

```
class Tv:
  def __init__(self, ligado=False, volume=0):
    self.ligado = ligado
    self.volume = volume

  def altera_volume(self, novo_volume):
    if(self.ligado == False):
      raise TvDesligadaException('Não é possível aumentar o volume com a tv desligada!')

    self.volume = novo_volume

  def botao_on(self):
    if(self.ligado == False):
      self.ligado = True
    else:
      self.ligado == False
```

Assim, quando tentarmos aumentar o volume sem ligar a TV antes:

```
televisao = Tv()
televisao.altera_volume(100)
```

A nossa exceção é lançada no console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 26, in <module>
    televisao.altera_volume(100)
  File "main.py", line 15, in altera_volume
    raise TvDesligadaException('Não é possível aumentar o volume com a tv desligada!')
__main__.TvDesligadaException: 'Não é possível aumentar o volume com a tv desligada!'
```

Caso a Tv, seja ligada antes, a pilha de execução segue normalmente:

```
televisao = Tv()
televisao.botao_on()
televisao.altera_volume(100)
```

Para evitar a interrupção da execução do código, você pode realizar um tratamento da possível exceção a ser lançada.

```
televisao = Tv()

try:
  televisao.altera_volume(100)
except TvDesligadaException:
  print('A TV estava desligada')
  print('Ligando a TV')
  televisao.botao_on()

  print('Aumentando o volume')
  televisao.altera_volume(100)
```

Observe que agora, caso a TV esteja desligada ao aumentar o volume, você pode capturar a exceção e finalmente ligar a TV antes de aumentar o volume.

Comment: entendi, mas se tivessem muitos metodos na classe Tv, tipo uns 50 ou 100 e nenhum deles pudessem ser usados até que o atributo ligado fosse True. eu teria que criar uma exceção para cada um dos métodos. Não é possível fazer essa verificação de uma forma mais geral não?

Comment: Sim, em cada método você deveria lançar a exceção caso a TV estivesse desligada, mas você não precisaria criar uma exceção para cada método, apenas uma exceção lançada em cada método.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde. Cachorro_Louco, infelizmente eu acho que não tem como fazer uma única coisa mágica que vai te impedir de replicar a "condição" nesses 50 ou 100 métodos. Use property e faz o if nos métodos que achas necessário.

```
class Tv(object):

    def __init__(self, ligado = False, volume = 0):
        self._ligado = ligado
        self._volume = volume

    def altera_volume(self, novo_volume):
        if self.ligado:
            self._volume = novo_volume

    @property
    def ligado(self):
        return self._ligado

    @ligado.setter
    def ligado(self, novo_estado):
        self._ligado = novo_estado
```

esse é o famoso "get e set" do python. Se usar property, poderá alterar o volume sem o metodo "altera_volume", mas, ao invés disso, simplesmente usar um self.volume = volume_desejado. Dá uma conferida no Property.

Abç.